# How to index list of strings in hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search, hibernate-ogm

How to index list of strings in Hibernate search?

i tried like this

```
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer_query"))
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> hashedTagList;
```

I'm getting error while committing new object.

I'm using Hibernate *ogm* with *mongodb*

Comment: did you try "Set<String>" ? It can't index elements of type Object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index element collections by using @IndexedEmbedded. This would be the easiest way to do what you want:

```
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
@IndexedEmbedded
private Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();
```

Note that you have to use Set so that the type of the contained element is clearly defined.

It's a workaround, we plan to fix the issue in a cleaner way in the upcoming Search 6.

You can also use a @FieldBridge to denormalize the data. The remark about using Set stays valid.

You can find the @FieldBridge we used at my previous job exactly for this purpose here: https://github.com/openwide-java/owsi-core-parent/blob/master/owsi-core/owsi-core-components/owsi-core-component-jpa/src/main/java/fr/openwide/core/jpa/search/bridge/StringCollectionFieldBridge.java .

By the way, you define an analyzer but you set analyze to Analyze.NO so your analyzer won't be used.

Comment: I followed this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608281/how-to-annotate-to-allow-for-searching-a-liststring-field-using-hibernate-sear

Comment: getting this error now : org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeException: Exception while calling bridge#objectToString
 entity class: com.healthelife.notes.entity.Notes
 entity property path: hashedTagList
 field bridge: String2FieldBridgeAdaptor [stringBridge=com.healthelife.notes.helper.CollectionToCSVBridge@56223ef0]

Comment: Well I can't really help you if you don't use what I recommended and you don't post the full exception. Updated my answer with a working setup.

Comment: sorry for not providing full exception,

i followed whatever you suggested only - StringCollectionFieldBridge

Comment: here is my entity class
----


@FieldBridge(impl=StringCollectionFieldBridge.class)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "customanalyzer_query"))
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> hashedTagList;


public Set<String> getHashedTagList() {
        return hashedTagList;
    }

    public void setHashedTagList(Set<String> hashedTagList) {
        this.hashedTagList = hashedTagList;
    }

Comment: org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = luceneQueryBuilder(searchString);

            log.debug("lucene query : " + luceneQuery);

            FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Notes.class);
            fullTextQuery.setProjection("hashedTagList");
            log.debug("jpa query : " + fullTextQuery);

            result = fullTextQuery.getResultList();

Comment: DEBUG 2018-03-09 10:14:41.856 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] (LuceneSearch.java:40) - lucene query : hashedTagList:hi*
DEBUG 2018-03-09 10:14:41.870 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] (LuceneSearch.java:46) - jpa query : FullTextQueryImpl(hashedTagList:hi*)
ERROR 2018-03-09 10:14:41.919 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] (LuceneSearch.java:53) - org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000324: The fieldBridge for field 'hashedTagList' is an instance of 'class com.healthelife.notes.helper.StringCollectionFieldBridge', which does not implement TwoWayFieldBridge. Projected fields must have a TwoWayFieldBridge

Comment: Well, the error is self explanatory, if you want to use a projection, your field bridge needs to implement TwoWayFieldBridge to be able to extract the values from the field and return your projection. Frankly, I wouldn't use a projection for that and just get my entities and get the hashedTagList from there. If you really want to do a projection, you need to tweak my field bridge to make it a TwoWayFieldBridge and extract the values from the Lucene document. You have an example here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-custom-numericfieldbridge .

Comment: Note that yours will be a bit different as your field is multivalued. Could you try the IndexedEmbedded + Field solution I put in my answer (i.e. without the FieldBridge), I'm not sure but maybe it will avoid all this work and have the projection working automagically.